# addslashes() example with NULL byte?

Tags: php

What is NUL or NULL byte and how escaping works with NULL byte?

Can someone please give example?

single quote and double quote is very obvious but i am not clear about NULL byte.

Documentation from PHP.net.

addslashes() returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted in database queries etc. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).

I tried something like this:

```
$a = NULL;
$str = " NULL example $a ";
echo addslashes($str);
```

But i don't see any added slash in output.

Comment: Don't ever use `addslashes` for escaping of database queries.

Comment: yes that's fine, i use PDO specific prepare statement..

Comment: @Praveen: wondered that you spent several minutes for writing the question instead of spending seconds to search in google (yes, it gives **a lot** of [relevant information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) even on the first page)

Comment: [Null byte injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_byte_injection) happens when a null character (hex or ascii char zero) is sent in the HTTP request, and is used to modify file paths for disk reads or file inclusion taken from user input.  addslashes escapes the null byte against this.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question, he's just confused the NULL value with the NUL byte.

Comment: @knittl escaping database queries makes very little sense, no matter what function used ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` is included in a string like this:

```
$string = "This is a NULL character: \x00";
```

Answer (score -1):

addslashes serves no useful function whatsoever and is a throwback to the bad old days.  You should never ever ever ever absolutely NEVER use it for anything.  Ever.  If you need to escape input for storage in a database then use the proper escaping functions (PDO escape, mysql_real_escape_string, pg_escape_string, etc)

Comment: there is no harm from this function either, if it's used to escape mysql strings in most widely used encodings.

Comment: That's so wrong I don't know where to even start.  It's possibly the most harmful function there is if you're relying on it for security.  This is why magic quotes are removed in PHP 5.4

Comment: magic quotes has nothing to do with addslashes. You'd better start from something, so, I'd have a chance to enlighten you :)

Comment: magic quotes is just automatic addslashes.  Neither work when it comes to making data safe for injecting into an SQL query.

Comment: so, it is magic quotes you against to, not addslashes. okay, -1 then, because magic quotes is offtopic in this question.

Comment: The only point of agreement we have - this function has nothing to do with security and should never be used for whatever security matters. As well as PDO escape and mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: I disagree with not using it for anything. I'm querying things from the db and building JSON strings with the results. The JSON strings get messed up if there's any " or ' characters and thus addslashes has come in handy for me.

Comment: @Galway Doesn't json_encode() produce a satisfactory result?